# Make navigation bar transparent regarding below image in iOS 8.1

Tags: ipad, swift, ios8.1

I try to set my navigation bar transparent regarding a image below this, something like the following image :

[image]

I tried the solution in [transparent navigation bar ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845855/transparent-navigation-bar-ios) but I don't get the above result, I get only the icon on the left but without any color in the navigation bar, completely transparent. But if I set a background color the transparency disappears at all.

There is any way to set a color in the navigation bar and make it transparent??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

just checked on the 8.1 simulator and got very similar result to your picture

```
    let bar:UINavigationBar! =  self.navigationController?.navigationBar

    bar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    bar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    bar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.3, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.3)
```

main point here is background color with alpha.

Check attached image, maybe I missed something?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that understand your question, did you ask about Alpha Chanel of color?

Comment: Thanks @sage44, don't worry about it

Answer (score 13):

To set this style globally, use the UIAppearance APIs. In AppDelegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` add the following code:

```
// Sets background to a blank/empty image
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
// Sets shadow (line below the bar) to a blank image
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
// Sets the translucent background color
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.3, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.3)
// Set translucent. (Default value is already true, so this can be removed if desired.)
UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = true
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the correct answer. The other answers must not have been tested recently.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the navigationBar's alpha property? In your root view controller to the navigation controller...

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setAlpha:0.3f];
```

Comment: when you set alpha to view does it also apply to subviews ?

Comment: I believe it does which is why you could set the background color to have the non-opaque color with `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:0.5]];`

Comment: I believe that alpha value of background color not the same as alpha property of UIView, but you can check ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

If the above code is not working then set edgesForExtendedLayout to all.

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .all
```