# How to get transparent UIToolbar or UINavigationBar in iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

I would like an entirely transparent UIToolbar and/or UINavigationBar. I have tried the many suggestion but didn't works.
This is my Code for navBar

```
  navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics:.Default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

This is a good example "the App Store"

[image]

Comment: this can help you in the case of the `UINavigationBar` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708943/make-navigation-bar-transparent-regarding-below-image-in-ios-8-1

Comment: @VictorSigler This isn't a native design for ios, I checked it already

Comment: The navigation in the App Store is not transparent!!!

Comment: :) What! I feel stupid, what is it then?

Comment: My point above is that it doesn't feel native

Comment: According to Photoshop its RGB is (214,222, 224)

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure you don't have something behind your tool bar. Like a collection view and so on.