# transparent navigation bar 's bar button items

Tags: swift, swift2, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uibaritem

I use this code to make my navigation bar transparent to make the background image continue to whole screen:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

then when I add bar button to my navigation bar, buttons are also becomes transparent. But I don't want my buttons to be transparent. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: These links might help 1.[transparent navigation bar ios](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35282448/452708), 2[Make navigation bar transparent regarding below image in iOS 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708943/make-navigation-bar-transparent-regarding-below-image-in-ios-8-1)

Answer (score 0):

Choose one of the `init` options which allows you to customise the button contents, like `initWithCustomView:` or `initWithImage:style:target:action:`.