# Setting a background color with alpha in Navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationbar, alpha, uicolor

I'd like the background of a navigation bar to be a color with 0.5 alpha to be able to partially see the contents of the view below. I've tried to do like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
}
```

If I set `isTranslucent` to `true`, then the `navigationBar` color is clear. If I set `isTranslucent` to `false`, the color is opaque even if I set `UIColor.blue.alpha(0.5)`

How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the `NavigationBar` (excluding status bar) background with alpha.. Try this

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
}
```

If you want background color with alpha including `status bar`, Im afraid you have to use an image with alpha value. [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25846056/1825618)

Comment: Thanks, I only need to apply that color to the navigation bar, but when doing as you have posted, I see that it also affects the status bar and now I see it in clear background color. Is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a image of the desired colour and transparency and then in your `AppDelegate` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function simply add this:

```
//navigation bar
        let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "nav.png")
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage, for: .default)
```

where `nav.png` is your image.

Hope this helps. :)