# Navigation bar color changes to black in pushed view controller in swift2.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, colors, uinavigationbar

Dashboard is a UINavigationController as root view controller. I put some lines in AppDelegate to make it transparent:

```
let barAppearace = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
barAppearace.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -400), forBarMetrics:UIBarMetrics.Default)
barAppearace.setTitleTextAttributes(["NSFontAttributeName":UIFont.customFontOfSize(14, style: FontName.kHelveticaNeue)], forState: .Normal)
barAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

[image: Homepage navigationbar having transparent navigation bar.]

when I push a view controller from Dashboard, pushed view controller navigation bar color changes to black.

[image: pushed view controller navigation bar]

I want same appearance as Dashboard navigationbar. I have gone through already answered question. But still no luck.

Comment: add some code. How u r trying to change color?

Comment: see this once may be it helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845855/transparent-navigation-bar-ios

Comment: On Dashboard screen its working fine. But when I push a view controller from Dashboard screen. The newly pushed controller navbar color changes to black.

Comment: else show your code

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Edited Question and included the code also.

Comment: check once are you disabled the `isTranslucent`

Comment: can you try with this line in your viewwillappear () method.
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

Comment: @AnveshTokala navigationBar.isTranslucent value is true by default. We must keep it true. Not False

Comment: What are you doing in the next view controller? related to navigation bar

Answer (score 1):

For complete transparent Navigation bar

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

You can even use this code for a base class and inherit it for transparent navigation bar.

Comment: I know this JhanviR. Thanks for this. I tried this already, but still I was not getting the transparent Navigationbar in pushed view controller. Though I was getting the required effect on Dashboad.

Answer (score 0):

```
let barAppearace = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
barAppearace.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -400), forBarMetrics:UIBarMetrics.Default)
barAppearace.setTitleTextAttributes(["NSFontAttributeName":UIFont.customFontOfSize(14, style: FontName.kHelveticaNeue)], forState: .Normal)
barAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)

I put a background image in view controller and applied below constraints to it. I achieved the desired result:

backgroundImage.centerX = view.CenterX
backgroundImage.centerY = view.CenterY
backgroundImage.height = view.height
backgroundImage.width = view.width

* view: Managed by viewcontroller property view.
* backgroundImage: subview added to view with above constraints.
```

Comment: were you doing the same in dashboard view controller too? to get that yellow image?

Comment: @hardikparmar yes