# How to make navigation bar transparent with a back button and the webView will display until the edge of the status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, autolayout, uinavigationbar

How to make navigation bar transparent with a back button and the webView will display until the edge of the status bar.

My webview constraints are all set to the edge of `Superview`

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845855/transparent-navigation-bar-ios) but I got the following results. [image: Pic]

I have also tried the following code at `appdelegate.m`

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBarAppearance = [UINavigationBar appearance];
navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[navigationBarAppearance setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
navigationBarAppearance.shadowImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -60) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But the webview also does not load until the status bar. It will stop at the navigation bar.
[image: Pic1]

I have run out of idea, please help.

## Displaying the WebView Constraints, it just won't display pass the Navigation bar.

[image: pics]

Comment: have you checked your constraint of webview?

Comment: Yes webview constraint are all set to the edge of Superview. Top, Bottom, Trailing and Leading

Comment: can you check it with UI Inspector it looks like webview is not at the edge or try to give some -ve top

Comment: Sorry Jasmeet, can you please elaborate how to check with UI Inspector. I have tried negative values at the top. It works but then different phones will have different top negative values and the display is not consistent over all phones.

Comment: please check the answer below it will work on all the screen as we will set the constraint programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get navbar height by, This will work for all screens

```
let height  =   self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height
```

and you need to set the top constraint of your webview to -ve to this value. first, take the reference of the top constraint say

```
@IBoutlet weak var topRefWebView:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

set its value at view will appear

```
let height  =   self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height
topRefWebView = -1 * height
```

Comment: i see how you are doing it, I haven't try but I think it will work. Is there a way to set it at appDelegate?

Comment: why you want to set it at appDelegate?

Comment: So it applies to all my webView?

Comment: You can create a webview class say "MyWebViewClass" inheriting UIWebView and instead of creating UIWebView Object create MyWebViewClass object and in MyWebViewClass set the topRefWebView constraint. Adding code in AppDelegate in not a good code practice and  should be avoided

Comment: I just realise the Navigation bar has EQUAL height of 44 points. So I just adjust my constant of my webView to -44 and now it all works in all phones. Thank you

Comment: I think there is a bug in xCode, while I was fiddling with in the Story Board. Some of my VC's Seague changes to Present Modally, I am sure I did not touch any of them. I thought what happened to all my back button is gone. I have to manually Change it back to Push, weird.