# View is tethered to the safe area margin top rather than superview, how would I tether to the superview top?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I don't know why the safe area covered my view on the iPhone X, simulator, but in xCode's view debug it seems ok. Is there any option to hide the safe area view or remove it? thanks in advance!
Via the view debug I can see no view or nothing covered my view, it's all right, really strange.

I added this myView in the storyboard which turned on the safe area layout guide.
I tried set additionalSafeAreaInsets.top additionalSafeAreaInsets.bottom to zero but it's not working.

Here is how I do the constraints:

```
func setupGroupBView() {
    self.groupBView = myView.create()
    self.view.addSubview(groupBView) 
    self.groupBView.snp.makeConstraints({ (make) in
        make.width.centerX.centerY.equalTo(self.view)
        make.height.equalTo(screenHeight)
    }) 
}
```

I tried set the myView's top, bottom to the controller's view.top view.bottom to -44, -34 but still it won't work.

[image: please check this picture that shows the reality!]

Please help!!!!

Comment: ClipsToBounds? Layer.masksToBounds?

Comment: One possible issue is that your navigationBar is not transparent. Can you tryout making it transparent: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25846056/3883492.

Comment: isn't the controller embedded in something?

Comment: so while running the app you are getting the spaces at the top and bottom?

Comment: @Scriptable yes, but it should not been there lol

Answer (score 26):

1. In your storyboard, select **root** view.

[image]

2. In the **Size inspector** panel, uncheck `Safe Area Layout Guide`

[image]

3. On the **Add New Contratint** panel, set all margins to 0 and uncheck `Constrain to margins`
   Please don't forget to click on `Add xx Constraints` button in the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 22):

You can disable safe area layout guide from storyboard for particular view controller.

Select View Controller -> File Inspector (first tab) -> Use safe area layout guides (uncheck the checkbox).

You can also change it programmatically in viewDidLoad().

```
view.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Have you tried giving constraint through storyboard rather than programmatically?
Can you please tell that is there any object of safeAreaInset in your view controller in storyboard?
If so, try deleting it.

Answer (score 13):

If anyone is having this issue while using `UIKit` with `SwiftUI` in a `UIViewRepresentable` or `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, try adding this modifier to the view:

`.ignoresSafeArea(.all)`

Example with pseudo-code:

```
UIViewRepresentableView()
  .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
```

Comment: Does not work for iPhone X, iOS 15

Comment: This is helpful, but the toolbar is too small in this case. It hugs the bottom of the screen, as desired, but the content area does not rise above the safe area, as it does in the Mail app (for instance).

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you could change that from the storyboard also. just Select your view top constraint and then relate it with the superview. like that : 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want *create* your own view *without safeArea*(Google sent me here with my question: "**How to create view without safe area**"), I found next easy solution:
[image: uncheck Safe Area]

Maybe someone came here with same question..

Answer (score 2):

Try to config insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea and contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    scrollView.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storyboard, but you want to disable Safe area guides only for particular view, you can do it in Size inspector tab on the right, by disabling "Safe Area Layout Guide" checkbox.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The truth is I have another viewController's view embed in my NavigationController, that viewController's view did not optimized for iPhone X, after optimized, everything's doing all right.

Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 0):

do be sure to set modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
for the VC being presented -> then possibly follow other answers to tether to the superview rather than safe area

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and tried all above solutions.
It killed couple of days, finally I found issue in my app i.e, we are adding view controllers as subviews to root view controller and they enabled in `viewDidAppear`

```
guard let TabBarVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabController") as? MainTabController else {return}
addChild(TabBarVC)
TabBarVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

I removed `TabBarVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`  **Then above solutions started working**