# Have table view content go above or below main area

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am currently developing an app which as a need for a box with some information above a table view. Unfortunately, I can not create the required behaviour with a standard UINavigationBar or a UIToolBar. I have instead created a UIEffectView with a blur background and placed this above my table view.

As you can see from this example in Apple's Stocks app, the table view content extends below the main visible area of the table view creating a nice blur effect.
[image: Example From Apple Stocks App]

My question is how can I recreate this whilst keeping the table view have a correct bottom and top area (if I just placed the blur view above the table view you would not be able to scroll to the bottom or top correctly, it would be obscured by the blur view).

Comment: Please add some code or image for more details.

Comment: I have added an image to illustrate

Comment: Please check answer on this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845855/transparent-navigation-bar-ios

Comment: You need to change UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent value to true or false solve this issue

Comment: This doesn't work for me because I am not using the standard UINavigationBar, I am creating a custom one with a view

Answer (score 2):

Drop a UIView as header on the top of UITableview cell Using IB. and set the height of the UIView Equal to your CustomNavigationBar View. 
header view will hide under your CustomNavigationBar view and Cell start from the bottom of navigationBar