# How can I fill the top of view with my tableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation bar which is transparent and a tableView in my view.

What I want to do is to fill the all part of navigation and status bar with my first cell and remove the top margin.

Like this
[image]

But now it looks like this.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Possible dublicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845855/transparent-navigation-bar-ios

Comment: Possible duplicate of [transparent navigation bar ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845855/transparent-navigation-bar-ios)

Comment: My navigation bar is already transparent. But default position of first cell is not what I want for... Even if I set the tableView's constraint to the superView, it is always under the bottom of navigation bar.

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try to set `contentInset` of the `tableView` up to top of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let yOffset = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height + self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -yOffset, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

This solved my problem. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Please accept your own answer so the question is no longer listed as unanswered.