# iOS UI: background problem of transparent navigation bar with search bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to create transparent navigation bar like here [transparent navigation bar ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845855/transparent-navigation-bar-ios) .

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeNever;
    self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;
} else {
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
}

UIImage *emptyImg = [[UIImage alloc] init];
[self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:emptyImg
                             forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

And I have a problem because `NavBar` with refresh control and empty image has background hole and looks like:

[image]

Without empty image `NavBar` looks normal:

[image]

How can I fix this problem or maybe there is another way to make transparent `NavBar` ?

Comment: Can you add image on stackOverflow instead of any other website.

Comment: Hi @Valeri, maybe this will work for you `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.yourColor().withAlphaComponent(0.15)`.

Comment: Unfortunately not working