# Transparent navigation bar iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, ios13, uinavigationbarappearance

Can't create transparent NavigationBar iOS 13.

I have custom UINavigationBar, where I configure UINavigationBarAppearance in

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.configure()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    self.configure()
}
```

Configuration code:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
appearance.shadowColor = .clear
appearance.backgroundColor = .clear
```

And set it to:

```
self.compactAppearance = appearance
self.standardAppearance = appearance
self.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

And by the result I have this:

[image]

Expected result: NavigationBar should be transparent

Comment: try add `appearance.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [transparent navigation bar ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845855/transparent-navigation-bar-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

```
self.compactAppearance = appearance
self.standardAppearance = appearance
self.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
self.backgroundColor = appearance.backgroundColor
```

Answer (score 4):

Modify the appearance code to this :-

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
appearance.shadowColor = .clear
appearance.backgroundColor = .clear
appearance.backgroundImage = nil
appearance.shadowImage = nil
```

Comment: You can cut the last 4 lines. They are identical to saying configureWithTransparentBackground, and you’ve said that.